# Web App JavaScript QR scan on iPhone or iPad

Tags: javascript, ios

I have a web app and one of the functions is to scan QR Codes.

On Android i have no problem using some of these:
WebCodeCamJS
Lazar Laszlo
https://github.com/Kephson/html5qrcodereader

But on iPhone or iPad it doesn't work (for something called getUserMedia)

So far i have only ported a photo upload functionality based on webqr.com code but we are not pleased by the results.

Is there another way to acces live camera with javascript or other plugins?

The purpose is to make it easier to the user, right now we could not make a native App.

Thanks